if i have my own domain, can I somehow connect tokio::bind to it?
I recently got my own domain
and I wondered if I could somehow connect my rust-server to this domain
even if my computer has to be a host..
#[tokio::main]
async fn main(){
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("http://my_example_domain.online/").await.unwrap();
}

if I started it I get:
called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error { kind: InvalidInput, message: "invalid port value" }

so is there a way?

If the DNS entry for the domain points to the system where the server is running on just bind to the IP address (or 0.0.0.0 for any address on this system) - but use the proper syntax for binding as documented. If the DNS for the domain does not point to the system you cannot simply bind to add and hope that traffic magically ends up at your system even though nobody knows that the system serves the domain.

You need to configure DNS records for your domain to point to the host running your server - which could listen on 0.0.0.0.

the IP address of my DNS server is much more than four characters as indicated in the documentation and I don’t really understand which character means what. Id address look like: 0a00:a000:0:0:0:0:0:000 00.00.000.000 (I changed the numbers to zero and the letters to a)

Regardless, your problem cannot be solved within the code presented - getting domain traffic to hit your server is a DNS configuration issue. If the IP address for your domain as set within your name registrar isn't correct (IPv4 or not), then you have to change it. However you do so is a different question, but its off-topic on StackOverflow. For networking help, you could post on SuperUser but please research the topic further.

Or I guess the answer to your question is "No, you cannot bind() to a domain".

The proper format for a String to convert to a ToSocketAddrs is "<hostname>:<port>", not an URL for your example that means you'd have to use TcpListener::bind("my_example_domain.online:80"), provided you actually have at least one of the IP adddressses that domain resolves to available to you that should work (it does when I use my hostname locally).

Not sure why people think this is not a programming problem as you've simply not found the correct format for your string as far as I can tell, and that part in the documentation can use some work in my opinion.

Ah, got the wrong link above, should be tokio::net::ToSocketAddrs not the std one (not that it makes a lot of difference for the quality of the documentation).

The fix is relatively simple, you just have to pass it in, in a format that bind expects:
TcpListener::bind("my_example_domain.online:80")

Which will then try to bind every IP address my_example_domain.online resolves to in succession, the first one that is available on an interface will be bound to.
TcpListener::bind takes a A: ToSocketAddrs, and it accepts only a handful of formats, full URLs are not one of them, it internally forwards the string to std::net::ToSocketAddrs::to_socket_addrs, that means:


&str: the string should be either a string representation of a SocketAddr as expected by its FromStr implementation or a string like <host_name>:<port> pair where <port> is a u16 value.


Applying the <hostname>:<port> variant to your string gives a hostname of http and a port of //my_example_domain.online/, now we can understand why you get the error "invalid port value", //my_example_domain.online/ is not a string representation of a u16.
